# How should we apologize in German?

Tags: phrase, expression, phrase-request

The most common phrase in german phrase book for apology would be `es tut mir leid` or `tut mir leid` to mean "*it does me suffering*".

From the questions on the difference between *"entschuldigen"* or *"Entschuldigung"*

- [What is the difference between Entschuldigen and Entschuldigung?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4193/what-is-the-difference-between-entschuldigen-and-entschuldigung)
- [Kann man sich entschuldigen oder nur um Entschuldigung bitten?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1089/kann-man-sich-entschuldigen-oder-nur-um-entschuldigung-bitten)

it remains unclear when to use which.

How do you use apology towards specific situations? e.g. "*I am sorry for my late reply.*" in emails or "I am sorry, the person you've just asked for is not available"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both *Entschuldigung* (which is a noun; it is an abbreviated form of *ich bitte um Entschuldigung*) and *entschuldigen Sie* can be used in a similar way to *es tut mir leid*; unlike it, they can also be used when interrupting someone:

> Excuse me, what time is it?
>
> Entschuldigung, wie spät ist es?

(*Es tut mir leid, wenn ich störe, aber ...* is also possible.)

I'd express your example sentences like this:

> Es tut mir leid, dass ich mich so spät melde.
>
> Bitte entschuldigen Sie, dass ich mich jetzt erst melde.
>
> Frau Meier ist derzeit leider nicht im Hause.

*Leider* is another way to say that you are sorry. It is only suitable for a minor inconvenience.

Comment: I'd add that `Es tut mir Leid` is more personal (i.e. used if someone passed away) and used to express your own grief over something (=> I'm sorry) while `Entschuldigen Sie bitte` is used if you seek the acknowledgment of the other (=> Please excuse my action).

Comment: I'd group the German examples in three categories: a) when you are in some (even minor) way responsible. Then phrases involving the word "Entschuldigung" and its derivates are appropriate, along with "es tut mir leid". b) when you're not responsible (i.e. when you could substitute "I'm afraid" for "I'm sorry" in English). Then "es tut mir leid" and "leider" are appropriate. c) when you're interrupting someone or asking for something. Then you can only use "Entschuldigung" and its derivates.

Answer (score 9):

> I'm sorry ===> Es tut mir leid

---

> Sorry ===> Entschuldigung / Verzeihung

---

> Excuse me please ===> Entschuldigen Sie bitte / Verzeihen Sie mir bitte

Comment: Add-on: `Verzeihen Sie / Verzeihung` is antiquated, sounds very courtly. Furthermore, only use `Es tut mir leid` as `I'm sorry` but never use it as `Excuse me`.

Comment: @falkb correct addition. **Verzeihung / Verzeihen Sie** is in fact antiquated, but still in use sometimes. So thought I will use it also in my answer in case if someone listen these words, he or she will know about the correct meaning.

Comment: @falkb: Thank you.  I was going to post a question regarding the difference between verzeihung and entschuldigen.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, "Es tut mir leid" and also "Entschuldigung" are both replacing the old "Verzeihen Sie mir / Verzeihung". "Verzeihung" is/was strictly used to apologize for your own actions. "Es tut mir leid" is in fact also used to apologize for your own actions, however, the cause for the apology is then more serious (it comes close to the more formal "Ich entschuldige mich" then). "Entschuldigung" (or also "’tschuldigung" in modern slang) is appropriate in the daily routine.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not trying to be formal, saying "sorry" or "entschuldigung" is just fine. I use sorry in most situations even though german is my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning German, but a similar interjection appears to be "Wie bitte?". In this case, an apology for not having complete clarity or experiencing incredulousness about something just said i.e like the English "excuse me? Could you repeat/explain, because I don't believe what I've just heard!"

Comment: Welcome! What you are writing is essentially correct (I would not classify it as an apology, but it is polite and used n the way that you indicate). I do not think however that this is what the question asked for.

Comment: _Wie bitte?_ can mean: "Sorry, I didn't catch that?"/"What's that?" or it can mean: "No way!".

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the part of germany where u r in, the people you talk to and your social stand to them, like you would say:

to a friend -> "Sorry!" = "(En)'tschuldigung!" (the "En" is often not spoken and this is used, if you accidently hit your friend, or sth like that...)

to a teacher/professor/your boss/a coustomer -> "Excuse my action xy." = "Könnte ich um Verzeihung bitten?" (this is "good" german)

Comment: You are asking for permission to apologise?

Answer (score -3):

I would add: "Es tut mir Leid" is used when you're sorry about a situation you didn't cause, e.g. their mother died. "Entschuldigung" is more appropriate if you're apologizing for your own actions, e.g. you killed their mother.

Comment: Welcome to German Language and Usage Beta! Please try not to repeat information from other answers. If you agree with an existing answer, the proper way to show that you support the idea is by upvoting. If you are still unable, invest time in the site to reach the privileges.

Comment: "you killed their mother" wtf dude